# PyQt4 in Snow Leopard using Homebrew

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, pyqt

I'm new to Mac world and I'm trying to set up a Python + Qt + PyQt development environment in my OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard.

Currently, I have installed latest Qt Creator from Trolltech's website including also SIP, Python 2.7 and PyQt4 using Homebrew, but after these installation procedures, when I run *>> import PyQt4* in python interpreter, it reports that no PyQt4 modules have been installed.

What could cause this problem?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17613433/99834 for a full solution that works with OS X 10.7-10.9

Answer (score 3):

This would enable PyQT4 on OS X even if you are using the brew version or OS X version of Python.

Obviously you still have to install pyqt using brew: `brew install pyqt`

Edit `~/.bash_profile` and add these lines:

```
if [ -d /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages ]; then
     export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
fi
```

This will work with OS X 10.7, 10.8 and 10.9 and in addition to this it will enable all Python modules installed by `brew`.

Comment: I tried this but I still get the same import error.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python:$PYTHONPATH
```

If it works, you can put it in your shell's initialization file (e.g. `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zshenv`).

Comment: What if it doesn't? It doesn't work for me. I've installed both python and PyQt4 via homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this for [PySide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide), the Qt project's new python library, but the solution will work for you as well.

Locate the `site-packages` directory of the module. Running a `find /usr/local/Cellar -iname "pyside*"` in your terminal where `/usr/local/Cellar` is the install location for homebrew software and `pyside` is the name of the module. The find command should print a number of directories, one (or more) of these should be a sub directory of a `site-packages` directory. In my case, the module was located at `/usr/local/Cellar/pyside/1.1.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PySide`.

Now find python's site-packages directory. I'm not sure where it is by default as I've installed so many versions of python. To find it for the primary python you can run `python -c 'import sys; from pprint import pprint; pprint(sys.path)'`. There should be a directory in the output something along the lines of `'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages'` which you're looking for.

Now create a [.pth](http://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html) (a path configuration file) in this directory to add the module's site-packages to python's module search path. Do this (as root if needed) with `echo '/usr/local/Cellar/pyside/1.1.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages' > /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyside.pth` using the directories you found in place of mine. That should do it.